# Sharing Viewdata across Actions in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In mu MVC application page I've a Product page (Controller: ProductController, Action: Index) which lists all the products from DB. Now I've a "Add Product" link which offers a form to fill Product details. On submitting the from AddProduct action is called which calls for a StoredProcedure (modelled in my model class). On succesful addition I use to RedirectAction("Index").Now my StoredProcedure returns me a message indicating the reslult of addition.I want this message to be stored in ViewData and show that on Index page. How can I do that? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `TempData` instead of `ViewData`:

```
public ActionResult Index() 
{
    ViewData["message"] = TempData["message"];
    return View();
}

public ActionResult AddProduct()
{
    TempData["message"] = "product created";
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

And in the Index view:

```
<% if (ViewData["message"] != null) { %>
    <div><%= Html.Encode((string)ViewData["message"]) %></div>
<% } %>
```